# Spring web development advice

Tags: html, css, spring, spring-mvc

At the moment I'm learning spring and have the basic website running now on tomcat. Can I ask, how do you load images onto the website now and where do you store the images, css, javascript etc in your project folder?

Answer (score 0):

The answer depends a lot on your development/deployment environment. If you are using Maven for example, which has a specific directory layout, you would put the files in `src/main/webapp/`.

If you are using Eclipse as your IDE and use Ant to build your project, you would normally use `WebContent/`.

In any case, I would advise to use specific folders for each type of file. You can still use Tomcat `Filter`s, if you want to influence the headers that are sent with the files. (Important for caching, ...)

Comment: I'm using IntelliJ with Ant:

my directories are as follows

src > (name of project) > web > (controllers).java

war > WEB-INF > jsp > (files).jsp

Comment: Put those static content files outside of your /WEB-INF folder, so they can be accessed directly. i.e.

    `war/images`
    `war/css`
    `war/js`